# What does this MATLAB function do?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
function sk=skeleton_finding(x)

% calculate distance transform
dt=bwdist(~x,'cityblock');

% find the local maximum
n=[0 1;-1 0;0 -1;1 0];
sk=dt>0;
for i=1:4
sk=sk&(dt>=circshift(dt,n(i,:)));
end
```

Can someone illustrate with an intuitive image that applies this transform?

Answer (score 3):

### Skeleton finding

---

> **Skeleton finding** is the same as ridge
>   finding in the sense of finding the
>   centerline. The difference is,
>   skeletonization usually find the
>   centerline in an object described by
>   its boundary points, while ridge
>   finding seeks the centerline in an
>   volume. However skeletonization can
>   be done by finding ridges in the
>   distance map.

**D = bwdist(BW)** computes the Euclidean distance transform of the binary image BW. For each pixel in BW, the distance transform assigns a number that is the distance between that pixel and the nearest nonzero pixel of BW. bwdist uses the Euclidean distance metric by default. BW can have any dimension. D is the same size as BW.

> Here is how **CITY-BLOCK distance** is calculated by [bwDist](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/bwdist.html).

**NOTE:** You might want to replace the circshift-call with a loop. Here's [why](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/254436).

GoodLUCK!!

CVS @ 2600Hertz

Comment: Can you illustrate the effect of the function by an image?

Comment: @user198729: Why don't you create a binary image and see for yourself what the function does?